# Customize layouts on Page Layout ribbon's dropwdown

Tags: page-layout

I need to customize which layouts appeared in the dropwdown of the ribbon under the button of Page Layout.

This is because not every page is compatible with any layout and we want to avoid the user to make a mistake there.

Do you know any way i can perform this?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

Are the options inside http:///_Layouts/AreaTemplateSettings.aspx insufficient for your needs?  You can limit the page layouts that appear on a site by site basis in there.

Comment: In our application we have several layouts and not all of them should be enough for all pages. I need to restrict which layouts appear depending on the page i'm in.

Comment: Is this a content type issue or web part zone naming issue?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can overwrite that functionality. What you can do instead is maybe create a new custom Application Page to select master pages and page layouts, create an action menu for that page so that it displays in Site Settings, and using CSS or JavaScript hide the default link in the SiteSettings page.

I don't know if that makes sense or not, but that would give you full control over what displays and what doesn't.

Comment: Yes, absolutely but i did not create a new app page. I'm modifying this dinamically with JS and Jquery.